# Application Updater - Keep getting 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, auto-update

Im testing out the .Net application updater component as decribed here [Updater component](http://windowsclient.net/articles/appupdater.aspx)

Im getting an issue that when the client tries to access the update.xml file I am getting a 401 Unathorized access error.

I can see the update.xml file when I go to the url through the web browser. Any ideas what Im doing wrong?

The "server" part is just on local host.

**Edit**

```
//Retrieve the File
        HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        Request.Headers.Add("Translate: f");
        Request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        //Set up the last modfied time header
        if (File.Exists(filePath)) 
            Request.IfModifiedSince = LastModFromDisk(filePath);

        try 
        {
            Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();// this is where error is being thrown.
        }
```

Kind Regards

Ash

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running your uri through fiddler? - http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Using this tool you can see the request and response, and potentially work out what is causing the issue more than just a 401 error.

Comment: Info from fiddler - HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized You do not have permission to view this directory or page. Detailed Error InformationModule WebDAVModule Notification ExecuteRequestHandler Handler WebDAVStaticMapping Error Code 0x80070005 Requested URL http://ash-pc:80/SampleApp_ServerSetup/UpdateVersion.xml Physical Path C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SampleApp_ServerSetup\UpdateVersion.xml Logon Method Anonymous Logon User Anonymous

Answer (score 0):

Is your computer connecting to the Internet via an authenticating web proxy? If it is, .NET won't talk to the proxy unless the application configuration file contains a bit like this:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true"/>
</system.net>
```